# Problem in derivation of Rydberg Equation

Tags: energy, electrons, atomic-physics

In deriving the **Rydberg Equation** I found that
$\delta E=E_2-E_1=hf$ where $E_1$ is the energy the orbit in which the electron was and $E_2$ is the energy of the orbit in which the electron is transferred to and $f$ is the frequency of releasedd photon.

Now shouldn't there be $nhf$ instead of $hf$. If one electron is transferred, then is only one photon released resulting $1\times hf$? Does this have any proof that only one photon is released?

If more than one photon is released, then why isn't there $nhf$?

Comment: Rydberg did not know about photons, but he analyzed the atomic emission lines and arrived at the Rydberg-Ritz combination principle. Frequencies are known.

Comment: If a photon is being released, then $E_1>E_2$ so $E_2-E_1$ is negative.

Comment: The probability of two-photon emission is generally much less than the probability of one-photon emission.

Comment: @G. Smith Can you show me how the probability is less for two photon emission

Comment: It is a lengthy calculation that does not fit in a comment. The calculation was first done by Breit and Teller in 1940 using second-order perturbation theory. You can read their paper here: http://adsbit.harvard.edu//full/1940ApJ....91..215B/0000215.000.html See section II.

Comment: All you really need to understand is that the probability of an $n$-photon emission is proportional to $\alpha^n$ where $\alpha$ is the fine structure constant. Think of $\alpha$ as the probability that an electron and a photon interact.

Comment: @G. Smith Then according to you the probability of a multi photon emission is greater than a single photon emission as $n$ is greater and so $\alpha^n$ is greater for multi photon emission.

Comment: No. Look up the value of the fine structure constant.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're correct that multiphoton processes (processes caused by the absorption/emission of multiple photons) are allowed, they're just less probable than single photon processes.

I'm not sure there's a simple ``semiclassical'' justification for this, but it's clear in quantum mechanics. If you were to calculate the transition matrix element in perturbation theory, your initial state would be two photons and an electron in the $i$th atomic orbital, and the final state would be an electron in the $j$th atomic orbital. The interaction between the electron and the electromagnetic field is $e j\cdot A$ where $j$ is the electron current and $A$ the electromagnetic potential. Since we have two photons in the initial state, we need two factors of $A$ to contract with to get a nonzero matrix element, so we have to go to second order perturbation theory (which we didn't have to do for a single photon process). Second order perturbation theory loosely speaking involves the square of the interaction operator, which when you're careful about all the factors gives you a prefactor of $e^2/(\hbar c)\sim 1/137$ relative to the first order process. So each time you consider a process involving an additional photon you add another factor of a small number, making it usually less probable.

I'm not sure if that made much sense since it relies on some understanding of quantum mechanics. The handwavy answer is that there's a probability of emitting/absorbing a photon, and the probability of doing that that multiple times involves the square of the probability you started with so it's less probable. I'm not sure what the early founders of quantum mechanics thought about this, maybe they just postulated that only single photon processes are important.